# How to exclude directory in rpm mapping in pom file?

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin

I have a pom file that creates an RPM artifact, and the RPM installs `/tmp/some_script.sh` into `/etc/init.d/some_script`.

It does indeed accomplish this, but it also tries to install `/etc/init.d` before it installs `/etc/init.d/some_script`. In other words, if I run:

```sh
rpm -qlp my_rpm.rpm
```

I get:

```
/etc/init.d
/etc/init.d/some_script
.....
```

How can I force it not to install `/etc/init.d`?

---

Here's the relevant configuration:

```xml
<mapping>
    <directory>/etc/init.d</directory>
    <username>root</username>
    <groupname>root</groupname>
    <sources>
        <source>
            <location>/tmp/some_script.sh</location>
            <destination>some_script</destination>
        </source>
    </sources>
</mapping>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [rpm-maven-plugin](http://mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/map-params.html):

```xml
<mapping>
    <directory>/etc/init.d</directory>
    <!-- Set this to false -->
    <directoryIncluded>false</directoryIncluded>
    <username>root</username>
    <groupname>root</groupname>
    <sources>
        <source>
            <location>/tmp/some_script.sh</location>
            <destination>some_script</destination>
        </source>
    </sources>
</mapping>
```

Comment: It works like a charm! Still, it would be nice to have the Codehaus documentation available again...